# iff command issue in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Hi I am newbie in MS Access I am using the following expression to calculate the balance of my wallet

```
Balance: Nz(IIf([In]=Yes,Sum([Cost]),0))-Nz(IIf([In]=No,Sum([Cost]),0))
```

I want to take difference of two sums, one with [In] = Yes and other with [In] = No, this will tell me the balance of the whole transactions, I have written the fomula given above I dunno why its not working

Comment: yes it says syntax(Comma) error ......

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder your expression:

```
Balance: Sum(IIf([In]="Yes",Nz([Cost],0)))-Sum(IIf([In]="No",Nz([Cost],0)))
```